# unable to change kivymd button line color

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Ive tried using `line_color` function as provided in the docs, but it makes of  no use

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.factory import Factory 
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox 
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

Root="""
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex      
BoxLayout:
    id:Layout_1 
    
    MDRoundFlatButton:

        size_hint:None,None
        text:"MDRoundFlatButton"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        font_size:16
        size_hint_y:.05
        id:btn
        line_color: 1,1,0,1
        md_bg_color:1,1,1,1
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "MDRECTANGLEFLATBUTTON"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        line_color: 1,1,0,1

"""

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Root)
    


                        
Main().run()
```

The desired line color was yellow for the first button

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly it will still be relevant. I configured these colors in this form and everything worked:

`line_color: [255/255,255/255,255/255,1] color_active : [130/255,46/255,24/255,1] text_color : [196/255,196/255,196/255,1]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer , the issue was due to an older version of the library, seems to be  working pretty well with the newer one