# MDRoundFlatButton line_width function not working

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am uing Kivymd MDRoundFlatButton and functions like line_color, line_width are not working, how can i solve this ??

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.factory import Factory 

Root="""
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex      
BoxLayout:
    id:Layout_1 
    
    MDRoundFlatButton:

        size_hint:None,None
        text:"MDRoundFlatButton"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        font_size:16
        size_hint_y:.05
      
        
        #this doesn't work
        line_width:40
           

"""

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Root)
                        
Main().run()
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Tell us what you are expecting to see, and what do you actually see.

Comment: @John Anderson I've Assigned line_width: to 40 and several other values but none of them makes any change in the output,  similarly for line_color  function,  i tried to change it to red and there was no change - you can find the question about line_color error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375607/unable-to-change-kivymd-button-line-color

Comment: Did you try a small value, like `2`? Any large value will hide the actual Button.

Comment: @john Anderson Yes, i tried small values initially including values like 0.5 ,still no change

Comment: I am using kivymd 0.104.2, and both `line_width` and `line_color` work as expected. What version of `kivymd` are you using?

Comment: @John Anderson Im using version 0.104.1 maybe that's the issue

Comment: I suspect that is the problem, since those properties do not appear in the documentation for 0.104.1

Comment: Make this comment the answer. Because the problem is that the user is trying to use the API which is not available for the version of the KivyMD library that he uses.

Comment: @Xyanight I've upgraded kivymd and the problem is now fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mr John Anderson mentioned the problem was due to an older version of kivymd(ver 0.104.1)
Anyone with the same issue please consider upgrading kivymd to version 0.104.2 (or above)